# Oracle views user

Tags: oracle, object, schema

Now that I've learned about the concept of schema objects in Oracle and its order when matching the tables names.

For a sql query issued by user XYZ and accessing FOO_TABLE the order of preference would be to check

1. User table: XYZ.FOO_TABLE
2. User synonym: XYZ.FOO_TABLE
3. Public synonym: PUBLIC.FOO_TABLE

Looking at the following data of a view in XML:

```
<ROW>
    <OWNER>XYZ</OWNER>
    <VIEW_NAME>BAR_VIEW</VIEW_NAME>
    <TEXT_LENGTH>...</TEXT_LENGTH>
    <TEXT>
        SELECT *
        FROM SOME_NAME
    </TEXT>
    <EDITIONING_VIEW>N</EDITIONING_VIEW>
    <READ_ONLY>N</READ_ONLY>
</ROW>
```

If I want to find the owner of SOME_TABLE, can I just start looking at the following order?

1. User table: XYZ.SOME_NAME
2. User synonym: XYZ.SOME_NAME
3. Public synonym: PUBLIC.SOME_NAME

Best,
Will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're statement can actually be simplified somewhat, to:

1. User object: XYZ.SOME_TABLE
2. Public synonym: PUBLIC.SOME_TABLE

This rule applies to all database object (tables, packages, etc.).  The local synonym step isn't required because 1) it is a local object and 2) Oracle doesn't allow for a name conflict between local objects (i.e. you can't have a synonym and a table in one schema with the same name).

The only qualifier here is that if the view definition contains the schema (`SELECT * FROM SOME_SCHEMA.SOME_TABLE`) or a database link (`SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE@SOME_DB_LINK`) then the name resolution is done from the indicated schema (in the case of a DB link, from the schema indicated in the DB link's definition).

Comment: Oh, I think I got my notations wrong. Replacing SOME_TABLE with SOME_NAME. Now we need to go though all 3 steps right?

Comment: @Will: No.  In the local schema you will have a synonym or some object with that name, never both.  If there is a synonym, it will show up in [dba/all/user]_objects. Describing the extra step is not really wrong, it's just not necessary.  You're not actually skipping the local synonym, it's just encapsulated in the first step.

Comment: Right, I was asking under the assumption that I have a XML dump each of dba_tables (and also dba_views) and dba_synonyms and none of dba_objects. Then the additional step is actually needed I guess. But what about public tables?

Comment: @Will: I was speaking strictly from a technical point-of-view, not an implementation one.  If you'd prefer to use DBA_TABLES and DBA_SYNONYMS, then you would need to check both for the local schema. Also, to answer your question: assuming you meant public synonyms, they'll show up as synonyms belonging to the "Public" schema in both dba_synonyms and dba_objects.